# Weinberg Volume I Equation (10.5.10) on page 451

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I copy it here: $$\Delta'_{\mu\nu}(q)=\Delta_{\mu\nu}(q)+\Delta_{\mu\rho}(q) M^{\rho\sigma}(q) \Delta_{\sigma\nu}(q)$$.

$\Delta_{\mu\nu}(q)$ is the bare photon propagator, and $\Delta'_{\mu\nu}(q)$ is the complete photon propagator. Weinberg says the $M^{\rho\sigma}$ is the matrix element of two currents between vacuum states ($\alpha$ and $\beta$ are taken to be vacuum states in the following), proportional to equation (10.5.1): $$M^{\mu\mu'...}_{\beta\alpha}(q,q',...)=\int d^4x\int d^4x' e^{-iqx}e^{-iq'x'}\times(\Psi^-_b,T\{J^{\mu}(x)J^{\mu'}(x')...\}\Psi^+_a)$$, for arbitrary transition $\alpha\rightarrow\beta$.

It seems related to the form of photon propagator in the Heisenberg picture form. Could you explain this to me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please write Eq. (10.5.1) for us and explain all symbols used.

Comment: @0celo7 I added it the question. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: There is an answer at http://physicsoverflow.org/32575